# Somar valores e subtrair valores de outra condição

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Boa tarde

Tenho uma tabela com nome TITULO
Nela tenho tenho colunas com nome CODOPERACAO, VLROPERACAO, DTAOPERACAO

Tenho 2 registros diferentes de CODOPERACAO que são:
16 = Inclusão do titulo
28 = Pagamento do titulo

Pode haver mais de um pagamento para cada titulo.

Dentro dessas condições eu preciso montar um relatório que me traga o valor de títulos em aberto em uma data.

Como que eu faço pra somar todas os CODOPERACAO = 16 e subtrair pelos CODOPERACAO = 28  ?

OBS: (Isso considerando a DTAOPERACAO < '01-JAN-2017' por exemplo)

Comment: você precisa de ter o relacionamento, dizendo que a operação 28 é pagamento referente ao 16, se precisar de efetuar um pagamento para vários titulos, terá que ser uma relação n-n, se não basta colocar mais uma coluna amarrando a operação de origem

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/316225-resolvido%C2%A0somar-2-valores-mesmo-campo/    veja se ajuda

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID_TITULO, sum(decode(codoperacao, 28, -1, 1) * vlroperacao) sum_vlr_operacao 
from titulo 
where dtaoperacao <= '01-JAN-2017' 
group by ID_TITULO;
```